# Remove deb-packages from local repo and configure apt

Tags: ubuntu, repository, debian, apt

I have following directory structure for apt

```
/locate/repo/x86_64/dists
/locate/repo/x86_64/pool
/locate/repo/x86_64/indices
/locate/repo/x86_64/images
```

In pool there two directories which are debian-installer (contains udeb files), main (contains deb files). I want to remove a few deb files in main and use apt for installation.
How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean with "remove few debians"? "Debian" is the name of a distribution, not a noun; so what do you want to remove? and why?

Comment: I have a local repo with collection of debians(.deb files). I want to remove some of the debians from my local repo. How to do it?

Comment: i suggest to not use the word "debians" for .deb-packages (you also don't use "windows" for exe-files, do you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### maintaining your own repository

In order to make your `.deb` files indexable by `apt`, you need to provide at least a `Packages` files in `/locate/repo/x86_64/dists`. This file lists all the Packages (for a given suite), and includes all the meta-data (description, dependencies,...)

How exactly you do this, depends on your setup, as there are [numerous options to manage an apt-repository](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository).

One simple option would be to use `apt-ftparchive` (can be found in the `apt-utils` package):

```
$ cd /locate/repo/x86_64
$ mkdir -p dists/jessie/
$ apt-ftparchive packages pool/ | gzip > dists/jessie/Packages.gz
$ apt-ftparchive release dists/jessie/ > dists/jessie/Release
```

Finally, you need to add the repository to your apt-sources.

```
# mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
# cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myownrepo.list <<EOF
deb file:////locate/repo/x86_64 jessie main
EOF
#
```

After that, you can simply run `apt-get update` and your packages can be installed via `apt`.

### removing .deb files from the repository

to remove files from the repository, just delete them:

```
$ rm /locate/repo/x86_64/pool/ugly*.deb
```

after that, you need to (re-)generate the `Packages` files

Comment: How to generate Release files with HashSum containing in it?

Comment: apt-ftparchive release dists/precise/ > dists/precise/Release, has worked for me